# EventHandlers within an XML file and deserialization issue

Tags: c#, xml

I am not sure if that can be done, so I'll say that before I start.

I have an XML file which contains the usual stuff (strings, bools etc), but I also want it to have as one of the nodes the EventHandler for the specific click event. All click events are the normal object s, EventArgs e variety.

My holding class looks like this

```
namespace testxmlui
{
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("xmlformat")]
public class XmlFormatData
{
    private List<xmlformdata> xmlform;

    public XmlFormatData()
    {
        xmlform = new List<xmlformdata>();
    }

    [XmlElement("Element")]
    public xmlformdata[] Forms
    {
        get { return xmlform.ToArray(); }
        set { xmlform = new List<xmlformdata>(value); }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class xmlformdata
{
    public xmlformdata()
    {
    }

    public string buttonName
    { get; set; }

    public int buttonAction
    { get; set; }

    public int buttonEvent
    { get; set; }

    public bool HasEventAttached
    { get; set; }

    public EventHandler EventHandle
    { get; set; }
}
}
```

this is then deserialized using

```
private void GenerateUI()
    {
        XmlFormatData f;
        f = null;
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlFormatData));
            TextReader r = new StreamReader(pathToUse);
            f = (XmlFormatData)s.Deserialize(r);
            r.Close();
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}", e.Message);
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operation Error : {0}, {1}", s.Message, s.StackTrace);
        }
// there is more, but it's all UI code, so not really a problem
}
```

Do I need to do something special to include the EventHandler and can anyone suggest why I'm getting a deserialization error?

The deserialization throwback reads

Invalid Operation Error : There was an error reflecting type 'testxmlui.XmlFormatData'.,   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, System.Type[] extraTypes, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String defaultNamespace) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0 
  at testxmlui.MainActivity.GenerateUI () [0x00004] in /Volumes/Developer/Developer/ftrack2/testxmlui/testxmlui/MainActivity.cs:62

Thanks

Comment: Have u tried deserialising it without the EventHandler prop? That's the only thing I can spot. I have a similar thing in place, but I have method names in the xml and I Invoke them using reflection knowningly that they are against an entity called UserDelegates. Hope this helps u

Comment: Yeah, tried it without the EventHandler prop as well, gives the same error.

Comment: BTW, XmlSerializer does not require [Serializable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlSerializer is a data serializer - it does not and cannot serialize delegates / events, as delegates are fundamentally about implementation - not data. Additionally, serializing events means you need to cascade the serializer into many more types that are *outside* the expected model. So no, that isn't really viable with that serializer. IMO serializing events usually suggests a code-smell anyway - again, they are not the data.

Re the exception: look at the InnerException - it actually gives very detailed messages, but you need to dig down a level.